# Question about cycles in the symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Hello, I need help with the previous proof. I know that I didn't type it as it's suppose to be, but it's very readable and understandable.

My first question is what is c?. is it a one cycle?. If it is then how $\delta{(c)}=c$.

Why is the implication true in the second line knowing that $c$ and $\delta{(c)}$ are not in $\{b_1,.....,b_l\}$.

Can you explain the remaining lines in a easier way?.

Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: $c$ is one of $a_1, \cdots, a_k$. Since $\delta$ does not have $c$, $\delta(c)=c$.

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is one of the elements $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ being permuted. You can think of permutations as functions $\{1,2,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; to check that $\gamma \delta=\delta \gamma$, you need to check that $\gamma(\delta(c))=\delta(\gamma(c))$ for all $c \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. (Similar to how one would need to show $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in order to conclude that the functions $f$ and $g$ are the same.)

They break up into three cases.

1. $c \in \{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$. [Answering your other question: since $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are disjoint, $c$ is not one of the $b_i$, so in this case, $\delta(c)=c$.]
2. $c \in \{b_1,\ldots,b_\ell\}$.
3. Any other $c \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ not covered in the previous two cases.

Answer (score 0):

$c$ is one of the values $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ which are in the cycle $\gamma$.  $\delta(c) = c$ because $c$ is not in the cycle $\delta$.

Maybe a concrete example will help.  Take $n = 8$, $\gamma = (1,3,5)$ and $\delta = (2,4,6)$.  That is, $\gamma$ is the permutation that takes $1$ to $3$, $3$ to $5$, $5$ to $1$, and leaves everything else alone.  $\delta$ is the permutation that takes $2$ to $4$, $4$ to $6$, $6$ to $2$, and leaves everything else alone.  The proof is just checking that $\gamma \delta$ and $\delta \gamma$, acting on each of the values $1$ to $n$, do the same thing.
Namely in this case, they both take $1$ to $3$, $2$ to $4$, $3$ to $5$, $4$ to $6$, $5$ to $1$, $6$ to $2$, $7$ to $7$ and $8$ to $8$.

Comment: ok, so why can we say = $\delta{(\gamma{(c)})}=(\delta \gamma)(c)$

Comment: The "product" in the symmetric group $S_n$ is functional composition, so by *definition*: $(\delta\gamma)(c) = (\delta\circ\gamma)(c) = \delta(\gamma(c))$.